# How search for multiple values in string and return a value depending on the match?

Tags: google-sheets

This is my sample data

|  | A | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This doesn't match | ... |
| 2 | This one has Foo | ... |
| 3 | In this, Foo exists too | ... |
| 4 | Here we have Bar this time | ... |

I have in a different sheet the values to search

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo |
| 2 | Bar |

This is the result I need

|  | A | B | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This doesn't match | < nothing > | ... |
| 2 | This one has Foo | Foo | ... |
| 3 | In this, Foo exists too | Foo | ... |
| 4 | Here we have Bar this time | Bar | ... |

For this example the next formula would work

```
=IFS(regexmatch(A1, "Foo"), "Foo", regexmatch(A1, "Bar"), "Bar")
```

but in reality I have to search for values in a range, so can't list every term manually.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=map(tocol(A1:A, 1), lambda(t, 
  textjoin(", ", true, 
    ifna(filter(Sheet2!A1:A, search(Sheet2!A1:A, t))) 
  ) 
))
```

See
[map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985),
[tocol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258),
[textjoin()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197)
and
[search()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154).